# Can't create a MYSQL docker container with volume

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-volume

I'm trying to create a MYSQL docker container with volume using the following command:

`docker run -d -v $(pwd)/api/db/data:/var/lib/mysql --rm --name mysql-container mysql-image`

But i recieve the error:

> Unable to find image 'de:latest' locally docker: Error response from
> daemon: pull access denied for de, repository does not exist or may
> require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is
> denied. See 'docker run --help'.

I'm alredy logged in my docker account and when i try creating the container without the volume, using this command:

`docker run -d  --rm --name mysql-container mysql-image`

no errors occurs.

Comment: Is there a space in the current directory name?  Does putting the argument in double quotes `"$(pwd)/...:.../mysql"` help?